# Why can't I install the Pino twitter client in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I did a search for Pino the twitter client and it comes up but when I click more info it says here is a screen shot of it [here](http://imagebin.org/224300):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Pino hasn't been updated in almost two years (since January 2011). It was [only officially available in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pino), and is not included in 12.04. That's why you get the "not found" error.

You can install it from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fabriziosm/+archive/ppa-testing):

- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
- Type/paste: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fabriziosm/ppa-testing`
- Then type/paste: `sudo apt-get update`
- Close the terminal.

Now open Software Center, and search for Pino. You should now see an <kbd>Install</kbd> button. Install Pino; I tried it on 12.04 and it appears to work.

> *Related:* [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)